# How are subnet mask attributed to IP?

Tags: networking, mask, subnet

I am currently studying networks in general. I read a lot of things about subnets, and subnet masks, but there is one thing I can't understand.

How are subnet masks attributed to IP adresses ?
For example : 
How the network administrator tells that an address `A` will get a `255.255.255.0` mask, and an address `B` will get a different one ? (in order to create the subnets).

I looked up into my personal router configuration panel, but I did not see anything.

Comment: IP and Netmask is configured on each individual device. (DHCP might tell a device what IP/netmask it should use too)

Comment: it may be configured as /24 or class C is default on that particular router.

Comment: @MalteseFalcon, on a side note, did you used to play Counterstrike under that name?

Comment: @CustomX, hmm maybe, I don't remember... Why ?

Comment: @MalteseFalcon, I used to play with someone on Counterstrike under the exact same name and picture (if I'm not mistaken), he was 50+ though

Comment: @CustomX, I guess it wasn't me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subnet mask is selected by the network administrator to divide a network into smaller sub-networks. There is no rule how to "calculate" it from an IP address.

Let's look at an example with a very common subnet mask 255.255.255.0 which in binary is 1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.0000 0000.

A subnet mask will always have a certain number of zeros at the end. Above netmask has 8 zeros at the end, indicating that there will be 2^8 = 256 possible addresses in the subnetwork. Sysadmin might want to have a smaller sub-network, so (s)he can choose a subnet mask 255.255.255.127 which is 1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 0000 and will allow 2^4 = 32 addresses in the sub-net.

Edit: A sysadmin will assign a subnet mask to each IP address based on the administrative requirements. This is done during the design of the network. Let's say that sysadmin knows that in the new branch there are 100 people in sales, and 20 in accounting. Also sysadmin knows that he has 10.10.10.0-255 reserved for that branch addresses. So one way a sysadmin can divide 0-255 range is:

```
10.10.10.0-127   : Sales
10.10.10.128-158 : Accounting
```

Then the IP addresses and subnet masks will be:

```
IP: 10.10.10.0-127   MASK: 255.255.255.128    : Sales
IP: 10.10.10.128-159 MASK: 255.255.255.224    : Beancounters
```

In each address range 2 addresses will not be used for users: 1st one because it is a network number and the last, because it is a broadcast address.

This all can look like nonsense work for average home user where you can put all your hosts in one subnet, but once you are dealing with big networks this starts making sense.

Router configuration:

To route data *between* the subnets you need a router. In your average home router you have 2 *routed* interfaces - one facing the ISP and another facing your home network which is behind a (usually) 4 ports switch. On enterprise/service-provider routers you will have multiple *routed* interfaces - each with its own IP address and subnet mask. To make matters more complicated - in enterprise routers you can assign one physical interface to have multiple IP Address and subnet mask pairs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is very detailed.
In your example, the two "sub-networks" are existing on the same router.
My last question would be : how to configure all that stuff, if I want the two subnets to exists respectively on two routers ? Tell me if I am clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Subnet masks tell you how many of the the senior bits are network bits. For example if you have a network 171.20.20.0/24 this means that computers with IPs 171.20.20.5 and 171.20.21.7 are in different networks. Subnets ignore the network's class.

Comment: I know about that :)
But for example, when my computer gets its IP adress (when connecting to the router). Then the router tells him "your mask is ..." ? So it knows which subnet it belongs to ?

Comment: @MalteseFalcon It knows that because someone entered the proper netmask in the DHCP server configuration on your router. When your computer starts it broadcasts a DHCP request, and the router responds with which IP, netmask, gateway, dns server etc. it should use. That is just one way of doing things, and all those DHCP configurations might not be exposed via the admin GUI of your router.

Comment: @nos okay, I see...
But sometimes I see some "network schemas" with multiple subnet masks (that are different). In this case, are each router a subnet ? I can't find any document that explains that (a tutorial, anything)